# Transforming UIImageView pixelates the UIImageView image in iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, transform, uiviewanimation

I am transforming the imageView using the following code it works fine but it pixelates the images.

```
 CABasicAnimation *animation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"]

  animatation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0];


  animation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.05];
  animation.fillMode=KCAFillModeForwards;
  animation.cumalative=YES;
  animation.additive=NO;
  animation.repeatCount=1;
  animation.removedOnCompletion=NO;
  animation.duation=0.0;
  [needleImageView.layer.anchorpoint=CGPointMake(1,1)];
  [needleImageView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transform"];
```

Using the above code it transforms the image but it pixelates the image. Thanks

Comment: change anchorpoint as outside of UIImageview frame..

Comment: @iMani Can you please explain this to change anchor point outside of the UIImageView frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which ipad you are using ? If you are using ipad without **retina display** then it will pixelate on transformation.